# Adjust, sort and average numbers in different values

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

I have set of numbers like:

273 275,91; 30005;  0;  2738;   250,9371; 25;  etc...
Result of adjusting:

25000, 25093, 27327, 27380, 30005, 0

Result of sorting:
30005, 27327, 27380, 27327, 25093, 25000

They all have almost same value, in this case 25 000-30 005. I need take average and also sort them but they need to have the similar value. Also I wanna exclude zeros from the average.
They are always within range 50-150% of the average.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are looking to achieve. Can you show what the result would be for a hypothetical scenario?

Answer (score 0):

C7:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B5:H5; ">0")
```

C8:

```
=SORT(FLATTEN(B2:H5))
```

[image: 0]